# How to create R script launcher in cloudera cluster

Tags: r, apache-spark, cloudera

I have a R script written for some analytical application. I wanted to make it as launch-able service which can run run periodically on Cloudera cluster. I know for Python we can run it via `spark-submit` but I need it for R.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as Python or Scala or Java programs, SparkR programs can be submitted via `spark-submit`:

```
spark-submit /path/to/your/script.R
```

so you can use the same methods that you'd use for any other supported language.